# Add active class to all relative actions inside controller Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, haml

I am using the following `helper` to add `is_active` css class to active links in my navigation bar.

```
# application_helper.rb
def active_link_to(name = nil, options = nil, html_options = nil, &block)
  active_class = html_options[:active] || "is_active"
  html_options.delete(:active)
  html_options[:class] = "#{html_options[:class]} #{active_class}" if current_page?(options)
  link_to(name, options, html_options, &block)
end
```

This code works perfectly. However, I want to keep `is_active` class on every page which related to the controller. For example, here is my controller route:

```
# routes.rb
resources :catalogs, path: "s", only: [:index, :show] do
  resources :products, path: "", only: [:show]
end
```

and imagine that I have 100 different catalogs. I want to keep `is_active` on the index page, while the user switches show pages.

Link in my navigation bar:

```
= active_link_to "Products", catalog_path(1), class: "navbar_link"
```

*Please note, that in the previous line I am navigation to the very first catalog, not to the `index` page.*

Thank you for your help and time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [active_link_to](https://github.com/comfy/active_link_to) gem, which does exactly what you want. It would be something like this (not tested)

`active_link_to 'Products', catalog_path(1), active: [['catalogs'], ['index', 'show']], class_active: 'is_active'`

Comment: Thank you very much, works :) Didn't know about this `gem`